# Convert a date column to MM/DD/YYYY format in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, date, datetime, format

```
 df[Date"] = df[Date"].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

The above code is not working for me. I am facing the following issue.Please help me with the same.

**main**:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value` instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

missing `"` here